# Are there any real world applications written in INTERCAL?

Tags: intercal

Just out of curiosity:

Is there any real world application written in INTERCAL?

TIA ;)

Comment: I am not interested in postmodern notions about the relativity of reality or the subjective experience of "Existence". If there  is a program written in INTERCAL (or Python or Perl or C#) then for the mayority of humans it exists and  this is not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "real world applications".

If you're talking about code that's been packaged up into a piece of software and sold to the masses (something like a smartphone app or a videogame) I don't know of any and *strongly* suspect none exists. INTERCAL is too ahead of its time for most modern programming applications.

However, there are a surprising variety of things which *have* been done in INTERCAL.

### You can do math

There are any number of practical mathematics programs that have been programmed in INTERCAL. I myself have written several. That's not to say that people haven't written better versions of these algorithms in other languages, but it's perfectly possible to write them in INTERCAL and people *have* done it.

### You can write a quine

If you want proof that INTERCAL can be used for Serious Computer Business, you might consider the INTERCAL quine, found [here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/intercal/quine.html). While quines don't really do anything, per say, they are a real thing that real people try to do with real programming languages - and so could be taken as "real world", in a sense.

### You can access the internet

Perhaps the *pièce de résistance* of INTERCAL glory is the CGI script which takes INTERCAL out into the wide world of the internet. If you're interested, you can read all about that one [here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/intercal/ins/description.html). I think that's about as real world as it gets for INTERCAL.

If you want to further explore, [http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal/](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/intercal/) is a good starting point for finding just about everything that has been done with the language.